# Object has no method 'createApp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I'm new to Javascript. I'm trying to load the following script using Node.js  (ver. 0.8.8, it has to be done in this specific version), OS - Windows 10:

```
//require('look').start();
var main = require('skilap-core');
if (process.argv[2]=="automated") {
    process.on("message",function (msg) {
        if (msg.c == "startapp") {
            var app = main.createApp(msg.data);
            app.startApp(__dirname+"/data",function (err) {
                process.send({c:"startapp_repl",data:err})
            });
        }
    })
} else {
    var app = main.createApp();
    app.startApp(__dirname+"/data",function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    module.exports = app;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createApp'
    at Object.<anonymous> D:\Downloads\skilap\skilap\app.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback(node.js:244:9)
```

As I understand, the module loads correctly, but doesn't compile. I've done research in the web and also saw other related questions on this site, but I cannot see what the problem actually is. What does the error mean and what needs to be changed to launch the app? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `skilap-core` code you've written? Maybe share it on here in your question if it's not too big, or add it to pastebin so we can take a look at help debug the problem.

Comment: No, I didn't write the module, so I wouldn't want to post it. But it's definitely a working code

Comment: Well, the error is telling you that `main` has no `createApp` method, so you need to look into that further. We can't help you if we can't see the code.

Comment: This npm module: [skilap-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skilap-core)? I'm assuming you ran `npm install skilap-core` to install it into your node project, correct?

Comment: @phentnil Thank you, I did it, but I got another error:  npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Comment: Why is this module or code needing to be loaded under such an old Node.js version? What's the goal of your project? That module also doesn't appear to be complete nor intended to be published to the npm registry if I had to guess.

Comment: That version is recommended by the developers of the project because it has been tested and proved working on it. I have received this project and instructions how to run it - there was only the command "node app" without "npm install", so maybe it was not intended to be published, I cannot say. The project folder and running "node app" (app - script name) should be enough to start the app.

Comment: They tested the app on Linux, but it should be possible to run it on Windows using Node.js, too, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, as long as configurations are good. I don't see anything in your code which wouldn't allow it to run on Windows. Can you confirm whether [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skilap-core) is the module you have installed in your `package.json`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's this module - unfortunately, the file exploring feature is not available for me (it's exclusive for teams, as the site says). By now I got it launching without errors (I've made small changes to the way the function is exported in the module), but now I have another problem - the page which should be opened by this app doesn't load, it says "Can't access the site"

Comment: Just so you know, Node.js ver. 0.8.8 is ancient (released 2012-08-22) and not supported any more. v14 is the current LTS version and v16, v17 and v18 are all under development now.  Here's the supported versions: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: Yes, I knew that:) I mentioned above why I had to use the ancient version - because of the recommendation of the project developers. However, I've already upgraded Node.js, and it seems to be working, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line `var main = require('skilap-core')` to `var main = require('./modules/core/lib/core.js')` (the path to the module file) and the module started working.

Answer (score 1):

You require a module I've never heard of:

```js
var main = require('skilap-core');
```

This is a javascript object.  In your code you are trying to call a `createApp()` method on that object:

```js
var app = main.createApp();
```

The `main` object does not have the `createApp()` function.

I would use a debugger or insert a `console.log(main)` after the require to see what the object actually looks like.

I used `npm pack skilap-core` to download it as a tgz file and examine it.  There doesn't appear to be a `createApp()` function at all.  It appears to want to take some kind of custome webapp as a parameter:

```js
module.exports = function (webapp) {
    var app = webapp.web;
    var ctx = webapp._ctx;
    var prefix = webapp.prefix;
    var api = webapp;

    app.get(prefix, function (req, res, next) {
        res.redirect(prefix+"/user");
    })

    app.get("/", webapp.layout(), function(req, res, next) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. According to the developer, the app can be launched with  the command "node app", no errors should arise. It has been tested and works on Linux, I cannot understand why it's not working on Windows

Comment: By the way, there are following lines in the code: 'var app = module.exports = express();'  'module.exports.createApp = function (cfg) {
 return new Skilap(cfg);
};' Isn't it here where the createApp function is defined?

Comment: webapp is also initialized and is equal to app (which does have the createApp method): self.webapp = webapp = app. But the error now says "TypeError: Object function (webapp) {...} has no method createApp(). I can't see why, but I'm new to JS